# Discord banall command not working | discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Hello I am creating a banall command for discord on a bot but it doesn't work for some reason please correct the code or give me a working command for ban all or mass ban

The Code:

```
    for users in ctx.guild.user:
        try:
            await user.ban(reason=reason)
            print(f"[-] BAN : Banned {user}") 
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `guild` object doesn't have a `user` attribute, so it will raise an AttributeError. This is supressed because it is inside a `try-except` block. You should loop through `ctx.guild.members` instead.

so your code should look like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def ban_everyone(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        await ctx.ban(member)
```

Comment: Thanks I made a silly mistake